# Trouble faking a Laravel HttpClient response

Tags: laravel, phpunit, mockery

I am trying to test the following bit of code:

[image]

DimonaClient is just a simple wrapper around a Laravel HttpClient; simplified function here:

[image]

The `getDeclaration()` response is a \Illuminate\Http\Client\Response

---

What I am trying to do in my test is:

1. Mock the DimonaClient class so I don't create an actual api call
2. "Mock" (use Laravel's Http::response()) the response I want so that I can test that a 200 w/ certain statuses dispatches the appropriate event (also mocked, but not relevant here)

My test code looks like this:

[image]

My issue(s) seem to be:

1. the getDeclaration() has an expectation of Illuminate\Http\Client\Response but I can't seem to create anything that will satisfy that (a new Response wants a MessageInterface, etc, etc... )
2. I don't actually need getDeclaration() to return anything for my testing, so I wonder if I should be mocking this differently in any case (I base this assumption on Http::response handling the internal code I'm testing for things like $response->ok(), instead of a Mockery expectation)

I feel like I'm one small step away from making this work, but going round in circles trying to hook it up correctly.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `Http` Facade, you don't need to mock `DimonaCient`. You are nearly there with your test, but let me show you what you would have done:

```php
/** @test */
public function it_can_handle_an_approved_submission(): void
{
    Http::fake([
        '*' => Http::response([
            'declarationStatus' => [
                'result' => DimonaDeclarationStatus::ACCEPTED,
                'dimonaPeriodId' => $this->faker->numerify('############'),
            ],
        ],
    ]);

    $dimonaDeclarationId = $this->faker->numerify('############');

    // Do your normal call, and then assertions
}
```

Doing this, you will tell `Http` to fake any URL, because we are using `*`. I would recommend you use `$this->endpoint/$declarationId` so if it does not match, you will also know you did not hit the right endpoint.

---

I am not sure what Laravel you are using but this is available since Laravel 6+, check [`Http` fake URLs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#faking-specific-urls).

Comment: Thanks, you got it!

I *did* still need to Mock because of an authentication call to get a token that was not included in my screenshots, but the rest of your setup got me there